# Setting a displacement or offset between Snake segements

Tags: c++, game-design, game-mechanics

I have a problem in maths or I do not know. I have drawn few circles that simulates the body of a snake, the head of the snake moves and others should follow.  but the is no offset or displacement between the circles, because the current code sets the previous position of the nodes to the current, when I add few numbers to both x, y axis, the body segments get distorted. How do I set the offsets between the segments?

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < nodes.size(); i++ )
{
    if( i == 0 )
    {
        // Do calculations for new position

        //Set position and previous position
        nodes[i].m_PrevPos.x = nodes[i].m_Pos.x;
        nodes[i].m_PrevPos.y = nodes[i].m_Pos.y;

    }
    else
    {
        nodes[i].m_PrevPos.x = nodes[i-1].m_Pos.x;
        nodes[i].m_PrevPos.y = nodes[i-1].m_Pos.y;
        nodes[i].m_Pos.x = nodes[i-1].m_PrevPos.x;
        nodes[i].m_Pos.y = nodes[i-1].m_PrevPos.y;
    }
}
```

I would like also to check the head's node velocity for example:

```
 if ( nodes[0].m_Pos.x < 5 ) 
    {

        nodes[0].m_Vel.y = -2;
        nodes[0].m_Vel.x = 0;

        if(nodes[0].counter--<1) 
        {
            nodes[0].m_Vel.y = 0;
            nodes[0].m_Vel.x = -2;
            nodes[0].counter = 5;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact you don't need to calculate offset for each part in each iterate.

just do it for first part. (How?)

```
for ( int i = nodes.size()-1 ; i >= 0; --i )
{
    if( i != 0 )
    {
        // Here Do not think about offset. just follow old position of next snake part
        nodes[i].m_Pos.x = nodes[i-1]m_Pos.x ;
        nodes[i].m_Pos.y = nodes[i-1]m_Pos.y ;
    }
    else
    {
        // Do calculations for new position "with a proper offset".
        // Is your question about how to calculate this offset ?
        nodes[0].m_Pos.x = .. ;// calculated position
        nodes[0].m_Pos.y = .. ;// calculated position
    }
}
```

About New head's position calculation;

Assume current head's position is (x,y). so new position simply can be calculate like this:

[image]

and more specific :

[image]

Comment: Yea, I would like to calculate the offset, I do not want the circles to overlap on each others due to the copying of the previous positions into the current positions. Furthermore, I'm trying to play with the head's velocity up and down.

Comment: You haven't mentioned this in question. ok

Comment: Thanks, so when I change the velocity of the head, I must check if its downwards or upwards directional, and then recalculate the offsets ?

Comment: Yes. It must be clear how to calculate next position according to x/y velocity of snake. you also can handle cross-direction ( for xVelocity=+1 and yVelocity=+1 ). If you need more clarity, I can explain more. but I think you got it. :)

Comment: I need more clarity, If you can, I stayed much to get it :)

Comment: It's up to you how to treat with player input.btw, first you apply player input to your two digital velocity variable (x and y). then you start to calculate new snake('s parts) position ( I guess in each frame loop). First of all you look at x and y velocity. if x velocity is 0 for example you know snake will go upward or downward. if it's 180degree opposite direction you should skip player input at all as a wrong input. else ( for this case) you keep x position value for new position but use y+2*r+y_offset. y-> old y. r-> radius of snake's circle-part . and y_offset->gap value between parts.

Comment: nodes[0].m_Pos.x = nodes[i].m_Pos.x-14;// calculated position
nodes[0].m_Pos.y = 0 ;// calculated position
I changed the code to the above lines, however the snake moves. I only want to set the offset without the snake body moves. I want to control the head's velocity on my own in another parts..

Comment: I can't get what you mean with your last comment

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10347/discussion-between-mahmoud-and-emadpres)

Comment: I saw what you write. Did you ask yourself where you used snake's velocity in your code? As I said you must have velocity ( let's call them: `x_velocity` & `y_velocity` ). Do you have them? Then you should calculate new place like this: `m_Pos.x+=(x_velocity*(2*R+OFFSET))` and `m_Pos.y+=(y_velocity*(2*R+OFFSET))`. Notice I assume velocity values are [-1,0,or+1].

Comment: yes i have velocities and as I showed in the code, I play with it. but m_Pos.x+=(VelocityX*2R*_OFFSET) will let the snake move it self and that's what I do not want, or I'm wrong ? I still didn't the above piece of code

Comment: "let the snake move it self and that's what I do not want" .. ? What do you want ? Normally in a game, we get input event, apply them into game world, and see result in next frame.

Comment: basically I'm trying to do the same snake that is here with the same movement style http://www.flashbynight.com/nanopedes/

Comment: yeah ! fun ! If you gonna copy that game mechanic your have two state: A) Snake is moving left/right and y_velocity is 0. for this state all I said works for you. but be aware that `m_Pos.x+=(x_velocity*(2*R+OFFSET))` in real coding should be integrated with elapse time from last frame trivially. B)Snake 'L' movement when hitting some obstacle. for this state you should manually hard code and change snake's velocity whenever is needed to copy that 'L' movement.

Comment: is my code correct that I posted earlier? why you multiplied the velocity  vector by that amount and not added it ? are you scaling it ?  The movement is really fast of the snake body. I will get the dt, and multiply the equation by it.